# trying to connect iPhone with Matlab - m = mobiledev

Tags: iphone, matlab

I am trying to connect my iPhone with matlab using this package

http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51235-matlab-support-package-for-apple-ios-sensors

When I run m = mobiledev in the command I get connected:0 instead of connected:1

I am using this tutorial :

http://it.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/iossensor/ug/mobiledev.html

If someone has an idea.

When I am running the connection using m = mobiledev, I get that :

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You seem not to have connected the iPhone to MATLAB. See the following article and connect the device first: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/iossensor/ug/set-up-and-connect-to-apple-ios-device.html

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did and it's still not working... @Matt

Comment: Go to the *Command* tab on the iPhone and enter for example `test=123`. Then check if the variable `test` is present on the computer as well and has the value `123`. Does that work?

Comment: yes the value is present on the computer.

Comment: If you go to the *Sensors* tab in the iPhone and tap on one of the sensors, it should give you a warning "*Waiting for mobiledev object to be created in MATLAB. [...]*". Right? So enter `m = mobiledev` and see what the result is. It should be `Connected: 1` in the first line, isn't it?

Comment: that's the problem, I got     `Connected: 0` in the first line...

Comment: see updated post @Matt